# Обмен данными по SSH роутер на OpenWRT и C# приложение

Tags: wpf, ssh, openwrt, c#

Добрый день. Есть задача. Получать\отправлять данные от МК Arduino на компьютер. Есть связка комп(Windows) --> роутера с OpenWrt --> и подключенный к нему по USB Arduino.

Доступ к роутеру с компа осуществляется по SSH. Проверил с помощью putty:

```
echo 123 > /dev/ttyACM0 // отправить строку   
cat /dev/ttyACM0        // получить ответ
```

Всё отлично работает. Но мне нужно получать делать это в своем приложении написанном на C# WPF. 
Сейчас разбираюсь с подключением по SSH к роутеру. Подскажите как это сделать? Пробовал использовать библиотеку [Tamir.SharpSsh](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx) но при

```
SshStream ssh = new SshStream(host, user, pass);
```

повисает и ни как не реагирует.

Подскажите как это реализовать или хотя бы в какую сторону копать ?!

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Только что наткнулся на [SSH.NET Library](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) и простым кодом

```
var client = new SshClient( host, login, pass );
            client.Connect( );

            var testValue = "123";
            var command = client.RunCommand( string.Format( "echo {0} > /dev/ttyACM0", testValue ) );
            var result = command.Result;
            //result = result.Substring( 0, result.Length - 1 );    //  Remove \n character returned by command
            List.Items.Add( result );
            client.Disconnect( );
```

без танцев с бубном, светодиодик на моем ARDUINO ожил)
Буду разбираться теперь как приманить данные) Если кто знает, прошу ответить)

Answer (score -1):

Ну и не красивый вариант запускать тот же самый putty c параметрами и ловить, что он там на делал через ответ.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process cmd = new Process();
    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe";
    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "-ssh mahi@192.168.37.129 22 -pw mahi";
    cmd.Start();
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("./myscript.sh");
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
    string output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Взял от сюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592329/run-unix-commands-using-putty-in-c-sharp